# How to import mp3 sound files in `nx`

Tags: reactjs, nrwl-nx

I am creating a nx project with separate `libs` and separate projects inside the `app` dir. One of the lib inside libs, importing few mp3 files and I am getting =>

```
ERROR in ../../libs/mylib/src/lib/sounds/sound.mp3 1:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

So it looks like a `webpack` issue can be solved with a loader, but I don't see any `webpack.config.js` file inside this `mylib` library.

I am currently new to nx and couldn't find where to add filetypes or what plugins should I install to nx, in order to, adding mp3 files in my projects.

Comment: You can add a path to a webpack config and create one: https://nx.dev/packages/webpack/documents/webpack-config-setup